# Why does fgets read the same lines over and over in wrong order?

Tags: php, file-io

I have been using `fgets` to read a list of (20,000) words in a file. It was working fine yesterday, but somehow now it reads the text file, which is simply a list - out of order, reads some of the same sections over multiple times. It's one word per line. A simple problem, but enough to stop your workflow in its tracks.

```
$fh = fopen('newsymbols.txt','r') or die($php_errormsg);
while (! feof($fh)) {
if ($s = fgets($fh,1024)) {
```

Curious if anyone encountered this strangeness from `fgets`. I am using this instead of `file_get_contents` because this particular script used `DOM objects` which eat memory in `foreach` loops.

Comment: yes I just discovered that feature -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not iterating through the lines because your while condition have to be setted with fgets

```
$fh = fopen('newsymbols.txt','r') or die($php_errormsg);
while ($s = fgets($fh,1024)) {
if ( feof($fh)) {
```